# WARN Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect\XConnect Model

Tags: xconnect, logging

We identified many repetitive warnings in Sitecore log files:

```
WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect\XConnect Model Converter | Convert To XConnect Interaction Operations / sec'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
        Message: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
```

It seems a permission issue. Please assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sitecore Version:** 9.2

We need to add our website's IIS AppPool user to “Performance Monitor Users” group.

Please follow below steps to clear this warning.

Go to **Computer Management**
System Tools -> Local Users and Groups -> Groups ->
“Performance Monitor Users” group and open it’s properties.
Click on “Add” button and add your IIS AppPool user for your site e.g. “IIS APPPOOL\sc92sc.dev.local”.

Here sc92sc.dev.local is my local website name.

[image]

**Reference:** https://tothecore.sk/2018/06/12/setting-permissions-for-reading-creating-counters-in-sitecore-9/

Answer (score -1):

Another easy way to achieve the same is-

- Run Command prompt as administrator and execute below command:

  `CMD> net localgroup “Performance Monitor Users” SitecoreInstanceName/add`

In your case it would be like:

`C:\WINDOWS\system32> net localgroup "Performance Monitor Users" sc92sc.dev.local/add`

execute this command and it will add your website's IIS AppPool user to `Performance Monitor Users` group.

Comment: thanks, it is good way to do.